# Get form hidden variables from a function to a php

Tags: javascript, php, html, hidden

this is my javascript function:

```
function GetCellValues()
{
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var str = '';
    for (var c = 1 ; c < rows.length ; c++)
    {
        str += '\n';
        var row = rows[c];
        var inputs = row.getElementsByTagName('input');                
        for (var k = 0 ; k < inputs.length ; k++)
        {
            str += inputs[k].value + ', ';
        }
    }   
    document.getElementById('hide').value = str;
}
```

This is my html tag. In this tag I want to use input type 'hidden' instead of submit and want to print this value in php page.

```
<form action = "project.php" method = "POST">
   <h1><u>PROJECT</u> :</h1>
   <!-- here I want input type 'hidden' -->
   <input type="submit" id = "hide" name="hide"onclick = "GetCellValues()" />
</form>
```

This is my php code:project.php

```
<?php
    $hide = isset($_POST['hide']) ? $_POST['hide'] : "";
    echo($hide);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to store the values from a function to hidden variable.If so then specify input hidden `id`.Try this:

```
<form action = "project.php" method = "POST">
<h1><u>PROJECT</u> :</h1>
<input type="hidden" id="hide" name="hide" value="">
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick = "GetCellValues()" />
</form>
```

**php:**

```
<?php
$hide = isset($_POST['submit']) ? $_POST['hide'] : "";
echo $hide;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood your problem. But if i did, you just use the javascript to modify the value of the hidden field. Then you use $_POST to give it to your PHP-Script. Something like this, not tested and probably wont work without adjustments.

```
</head>
  <body>
   <form action = "project.php" method = "POST">
    <h1><u>PROJECT</u> :</h1>
    <input type="hidden" id="hide" value="">
    <input type="submit" onclick = "GetCellValues()" />
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```